# Extrating the description with regex

Tags: regex

If I have this text

```
key: value
anotherKey: anotherValue
Description-en: A short description
 lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
 blank lines are represented by a dot
 .
 some characters like - _ are allowed here
key: value
anotherKey: anotherValue
```

How can I extract the Description

```
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
blank lines are represented by a dot
.
some characters like - _ are allowed here
```

with a regular expression ?

Comment: You probably do NOT want to use a regular expression in this case.  What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Regex will do it for .Net: `Description-en:.+?\n(?<description>.+?)\n\w+:`

Options: Single Line | Ignore Case

You'll get a named group `description` which holds your description.

[Test-Link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Description-en%3a.%2b%3f%5cn%28%3f%3cdescription%3e.%2b%3f%29%5cn%5cw%2b%3a&i=key%3a+value%0d%0aanotherKey%3a+anotherValue%0d%0aDescription-en%3a+A+short+description%0d%0a+lorem+ipsum+lorem+ipsum+lorem+ipsum+lorem+ipsum%0d%0a+blank+lines+are+represented+by+a+dot%0d%0a+.%0d%0a+some+characters+like+-+_+are+allowed+here%0d%0akey%3a+value%0d%0aanotherKey%3a+anotherValue&o=is)

Comment: Actually in the implementation in Java it only worked with the options "DOTALL". Ignore Case and Single Line were not needed.

Comment: "DOTALL" in JAVA does mean "the dot also matches all line breaks" its  like "Single Line" in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work in your case:

```
Description-en:(.*)(\n .*)*
```

or this one is even better:

```
Description-en:((.*\n)( .*\n)*)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tested that regex at http://regexpal.com/ but it selects from "Description-en" to the end.